# java code to take screen print in word

Tags: java

I want to take screen print in word and I am using the below code.Using the below code I am able to take the screen print in word but only two screen prints use to save in my word doc and it also replaces the old one and the new screen print use to get pasted there. could you please help me to correct my code where I am lagging.

```
    FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(strimage));

   CustomXWPFDocument document = new CustomXWPFDocument();

    // Adding a file
    try {

        // Working addPicture Code below...
        XWPFParagraph paragraphX = document.createParagraph();

        paragraphX.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);

        String blipId = paragraphX.getDocument().addPictureData(new FileInputStream(scrFile),Document.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);

        document.createPicture(blipId,
                document.getNextPicNameNumber(Document.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG),600, 300);
       System.out.println("5");

    } catch (InvalidFormatException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block " + String.valueOf(x) + "
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    FileOutputStream outStream = null;
    try {
        double x = Math.random();
        System.out.println("5");
        File file = new File("C:\\Selenium_Framework_Rajesh\\Scripts\\Eximbills\\SnapShots\\Mydoc.docx");
   //Santosh
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
       if(!file.exists()){
            file.createNewFile();

        String fileName = "C:\\Selenium_Framework_Rajesh\\Scripts\\Eximbills\\SnapShots\\Mydoc.docx";

        System.out.println("5");


                }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("First Catch");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    try {

        // Working addPicture Code below...
        XWPFParagraph paragraphX = document.createParagraph();

        paragraphX.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);

        String blipId = paragraphX.getDocument().addPictureData(new FileInputStream(scrFile),Document.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);

        document.createPicture(blipId,
                document.getNextPicNameNumber(Document.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG),600, 300);
       System.out.println("5");

    } catch (InvalidFormatException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block " + String.valueOf(x) + "
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
   document.write(outStream);
   outStream.flush();
   outStream.close();



}
```

Comment: This is the Javascript section, not Java.

Comment: This looks like an interesting problem, but presented in an unclear way. If I understand correctly you already have the screenshot files. So the problem is: you have N picture files, and you want to insert them into a (new? existing?) Word document, using a library (which one is it?). Is that correct, and can you clarify?

Comment: No while executing an application I am trying to take the screen sort of execution in word doc. Using the above code I am able to take only one screen print in word doc. But I want to capture the screen print of full execution in 1 word doc. Thanks for your response.